# Comunicar Backend con Frontend mediante Api Rest

Tags: php, laravel, api

les escribo para consultarles estoy buscando información pero no llego a nada concreto, el tema es asi:
Tengo un proyecto de estudio en el cual tengo que separar el back del front mediante una API todo programado mediante Laravel.
Al momento logro que el frontend consulte a la base mediante la API y me muestre una tabla, tambien logre desde el frontend (con un formulario) se agregen datos a la base (todo mediante la API),
este es el controlador que se concta con la api y le manda los datos:

```
public function registro(request $request){

$t = $request->json();
 $t = Http::asForm()->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user', ['usuarioNombre' => $request->usuarioNombre,'usuarioCi' => $request->usuarioCi,'usuarioApellido' => $request->usuarioApellido,'usuarioEmail' => $request->usuarioEmail, 'usuarioPass' => $request->usuarioPass]);
  return back()->with('mensaje', 'Datos Actualizados');
```

}

No logro hacer que la api me envie un codigo de status al frontend, para saber si se hizo el insert o no, cabe destacar que el backend lo probe con Postman y me muestra los status.
Para resumin, necesito hacer un login y registro que funcione en el frontend (laravel) y se comunique mediante una api al backend (tambien laravel) y poder realizar autenticación, al ser un proyecto de estudio, no puedo usar las herramientas ya proporcionadas por laravel para hacer el login, tengo que realizarlo yo mismo, desde ya gracias!!!!

Comment: Antes de avanzar por ese camino, creo que que deberías aclarar un poco cuál es la consigna/problema planteada. Pues por lo que entiendo, lo que estás intentando en el código es una comunicación backend-backend, pues lo que muestras va a ejecutar en el backend de tu aplicación para consumir una api externa. Puedo estar equivocado, pero PHP (y por ende laravel) es siempre backend. Frontend sería un código que se ejecute en un navegador o aplicación móvil, por lo que deberías usar lenguajes que se ejecuten ahí, por ejemplo javascript.

Comment: Bien, esa esa una gran duda, siempre eh utilizado php y sin la separacion de backend - frontend, en este caso estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Laravel e implementar una API, cosa que tampoco eh usado, tengo mil dudas, el hecho es que el frontend lo estoy haciendo con laravel para usar las rutas, pero la idea es buscar la manera de que se realice la conexion a la API (la api esta corriendo en mi backend)

Comment: Ok. Pero todavía no se entiende lo que quieres hacer. Por ejemplo, con la misma aplicación laravel puedes servir la API y la Web (en el mismo dominio), consumiendo la api desde la web con ajax. Otra forma sería desde una aplicación servir sólo la API, y consumirla desde otra aplicación (en otro dominio). Intenta aclarar eso en la pregunta.

Comment: La idea es tenerlos separados (así los estoy probando), backend con una API rest creada en Laravel, y un frontend que consuma dicha API, hasta el momento logre que el frontend consuma la API mostrando datos de la base de datos, tambien logre generar un formulario que envia datos ala API y la API la guarda en base, pero no logro que la api me envie de vuelta el codigo de estado (201 o cual sea), ya que la idea del formulario es crear usuarios (que tengo que verificar), dejando el backend asi, con Laravel, que es mas recomendable usar para el Frontend?

Comment: **¿Qué es mas recomendable usar para el Frontend?** eso va a depender del conocimiento que tengas de algún framework o librería (Angular, React, Laravel, VueJS, Django). Con cualquiera de estos puedes escribir el Frontend, incluso podrías hacerlo con HTML/JS/CSS, aunque eso presenta un desafío mayor a la hora de manejar las respuestas de tu API, pero sin duda puedes hacerlo así también. Saludos

Comment: Cuando hablamos de partir el front por un lado el back por otro y vamos a un entorno web la tecnologia a utilizar es ajax para comunicarse con la api del backend. Tu back/api no deberia de realizar redirecciones (con `back()` en este caso) si no retornar un codigo de estado http indicando como ha ido (ejem 200, 404...) y si es necesario o se estan obteniendo datos dichos datos en el body de la respuesta. Con laravel generalmente con hacer `return ['mensaje' => 'Datos Actualizados']` ya lo tenemos en este caso especifico.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas trabajando con Ajax para las peticiones debes de obtener el status

si sucede error

```
error: function(jqXHR, texto_status, errorThrown){
   console.log(jqXHR.status)
}
```

Si es correcto

```
success: function(datos, texto_status, jqXHR){
   console.log(jqXHR.status)
}
```

De lo contrario Desde Laravel podrías forzar el envío del código así

Correctamente se guardo la información

```
return response()->json($model, 201);
```

Sucedió un error al guardar la información

```
return response()->json([], 400);
```

Comment: Bien, estoy usando Laravel,
En el frontend tengo este codigo que se encarga de mandar los datos a la API:
`public function registro(request $request){
    $registro = $request->json();
     $registro = Http::asForm()->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user', ['usuarioNombre' => $request->usuarioNombre,'usuarioCi' => $request->usuarioCi,'usuarioApellido' => $request->usuarioApellido,'usuarioEmail' => $request->usuarioEmail, 'usuarioPass' => $request->usuarioPass]);
    }
`

Comment: Y en el backend lo recibo de esta forma:
`public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $notaNueva = new usuario; 
         $notaNueva->usuarioNombre = $request->usuarioNombre;
         $notaNueva->usuarioCi = $request->usuarioCi;
         $notaNueva->usuarioApellido = $request->usuarioApellido;
         $notaNueva->usuarioEmail = $request->usuarioEmail;
         $notaNueva->usuarioPass = $request->usuarioPass;
         $notaNueva->save();
          return (new project($notaNueva))->response()->setStatusCode(201);
    }`
pero no me muestra el status en el front

Comment: Y tengo configurado este project, solo con 3 valores, pero el valor del "test" no logro cargarlo tampoco, los demas si se cargan en pantalla, devolviendo en postman:
_{"data":{"usuarioNombre":"Manuel","usuarioApellido":"perez","test":null}}_

`public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            
            'usuarioNombre' => $this->usuarioNombre,
            'usuarioApellido' => $this->usuarioApellido,
            'test' => $this->test,
            
        ];
    }`